# PowerShell: Get-EventLog and Microsoft-Windows-GroupPolicy

Tags: windows, powershell, logging, group-policy

This question maybe dump, but how can I query the 'special' event log called 'Microsoft-Windows-GroupPolicy/Operational'?

```
Get-EventLog -Source "GroupPolicy" -LogName "Microsoft-Windows-GroupPolicy/Operational"
```

fails and below as well...

```
Get-EventLog -Source "GroupPolicy" -LogName "Microsoft-Windows-GroupPolicy"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry for the noise. Figured it out myself, using Get-WinEvent instead did the trick...

```
Get-WinEvent -LogName "Microsoft-Windows-GroupPolicy/Operational"
```